# MIP SDK error in Outlook add-in: profile_add_engine_async Failed with: [InternalError] Could not add new engine

Tags: outlook, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I have several VMs. All of them have desktop WPF app and Outlook add-in (based on Add-in Express). Both use MIP SDK. Today Outlook add-in started to get the error each time MIP SDK is used on 2 VMs. Desktop app still works fine.

**The error**

```
App.ApplicationId: [xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx], Pii: [None]
App.ApplicationName: [xxxxxx xxxxxxxx], Pii: [None]
App.ApplicationVersion: [1.0.0], Pii: [None]
App.SessionId: [], Pii: [None]
Event.CorrelationId: [b695308b-46a7-4f0b-adac-000023309402], Pii: [None]
Event.CorrelationIdDescription: [PolicyProfile], Pii: [None]
Event.Duration: [0.331102], Pii: [None]
Event.ErrorType: [InternalError], Pii: [None]
Event.Failed.File: [src\upe\api_impl\policy_profile_impl.cpp], Pii: [None]
Event.Failed.Func: [mip::ProfileImpl::AddEngineAsync], Pii: [None]
Event.Failed.Line: [307], Pii: [None]
Event.Failed.Message: [Failed API call: profile_add_engine_async Failed with: [InternalError] Could not add new engine], Pii: [None]
Event.UniqueId: [cd70a16c-2dbd-4e2c-b98c-0000d16252d5], Pii: [None]
EventInfo.Level: [10], Pii: [None]
MIP.Version: [1.3.215], Pii: [None]
```

I tried

- to delete the storage folder with MIP caches, logging, etc
- restart VMs

but the issue is still happening.

I was not able to find anything on the Internet.

Does anybody have any ideas?

**Environment**

- Windows 10 Pro 21H1
- MS Office Professional Plus 2013
- Outlook 15.0.5353.1000 32-bit
- Microsoft.InformationProtection.File NuGet 1.3.215
- AIP client is not installed.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try by updating Microsoft.InformationProtection.File to newer version (latest is 1.10.93) and see if the problem is still present?

Comment: This is not an option for now. The app is in production. Moreover, the Outlook add-in works just fine on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, we figured out that the value of the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol property in Outlook add-in was set to SSL3|Tls1. These versions are disabled in the Windows Registry.

For now, we just added code that sets ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to 1.2 at run-time.

We still do not know how to explain such value of the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.